# types googlemaps index.d.ts is not a module error message

Tags: angular, google-maps, npm, ionic4

I can't seem to resolve this error trying to implement google autocomplete for place search in my app.

I've tried most of the online suggestions to resolve this issue
typings install dt~google.maps --global
npm install typings --global
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
npm install @agm/core --save
npm install ngx-google-places-autocomplete
npm i -S google-places-autocomplete-service
npm install @google/maps

I initially got this error:
Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'googlemaps' instead of '@types/googlemaps'.

then after importing googlemaps I got the following error:
node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module.

One thing that's odd is in my typings -> globals -> google.maps -> index.d.ts file export class Map has an error stating there's a duplicate identifier.

I checked and that namespace is also in node_modules -> @types -> googlemaps -> index.d.ts.

So it looks like that namespace is declared in multiple files.  I'm not sure where it should be exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled everything and used the following code...much more simple.

I only had to install ngx-google-places-autocomplete

```js
  public handleCityChange(cities: any) {
    this.location = cities.formatted_address;
    console.log('location', this.location);
  }
```

```html
                <input ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options' #placesRef="ngx-places" (onAddressChange)="handleDesiredCityChange($event)"/>
```